# Error: 'X' must be a numeric or complex matrix [in a binary spatial autoregressive model]

Tags: r, matrix, spatial

I am estimating a binary spatial autoregressive model via a Gibbs sampler in R. When I do this using a neighborhood matrix, everything goes perfectly fine, but when I switch to a distance matrix, the program stops almost immediately, and outputs the infamous:

> "Error in ginv(A) : 'X' must be a numeric or complex matrix"

What strikes me as odd is that when I try to compute the generalized inverse myself, everything goes smoothly, and all the matrixes seem to be numeric. Below you will find the data and code for the replicable example.

[Data Link](https://gist.github.com/lessermatter/66b6488cfe6f5d7893bf)

Code (the error occurs after executing the final line, which is also a toy model to be estimated through the bsar function):

[Code Link](https://gist.github.com/lessermatter/0284be117a19620750aa)

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry guys, just noticed that the data was incomplete. If you go to the data link now, you will find the correct version. :)

Comment: Also reduced the data for the reproducible example from 3500+ lines to just over 550.

Comment: I can't source your data code, apparently because of the brackets ("<")

Comment: Hi Hav0k, please try again now. It was probably simply missing the initial assignment. :)